# Send a callback to AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Imagine a scenario, where a parent has a child directive. Something happens in the parent (eg. a button pressed) and the child directive needs to know about that (together with some callback data eg. button id).

Passing a function reference to a directive is usually used to receive a callback from that directive. In this case, it's the other way round, the directive is the receiving end.

A hacky way would be to pass a variable to directive, change the variable when a button is pressed and then `$watch` it in the child directive. But then again, it's hacky.

The question is - is there a native or standard way to access or call directive methods?

Comment: You can use `event`. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko the event is publicly accessible. I would like to keep separation as much as possible and only target the specific directive...

Comment: @ArtursVancans, the approach you specified doesn't seem to be "hacky", you can see a lot of angular as well as third party directives built like that.

Comment: `$broadcast` and `$emit` events is standard mechanism for communication between parent controller with child controller in `angular`.